# Catching exception from a called function

Tags: python, exception

I have a function that reads a CSV, checks the values in the rows, and if everything is okay, it writes the rows to a new CSV file.  I have a few validation functions I'm calling within my main function to check the value and format of the rows.

I'm trying to implement my main function in a way so that when I call the other validation functions and something doesn't check out, I skip writing that row entirely.

```
#main function
for row in reader:
    try:
        row['amnt'] = divisible_by_5(row['amnt'])
        row['issue_d'] = date_to_iso(row['issue_d'])
        writer.writerow(row)
    except:
        continue

#Validation function
def divisible_by_5(value):
    try:
        float_value = float(value)
        if float_value % 5 == 0 and float_value != 0:
            return float_value
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

At the moment, the writer is still writing rows that should be skipped.  For example, if a number is not divisible by 5, instead of skipping that row, the writer is just writing `''`.

So, how can I handle the exception (`ValueError`) raised in `divisible_by_5` in my for loop so I don't write lines that raise an exception?

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer on what exactly you expect and what doesn't work? What is the question?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can re-raise an exception caught in an exception handler and have another handler up the call stack handle it by using **an empty** [`raise`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions) statement **inside** the `except` block:

```
except ValueError:
    raise  # re raises the previous exception
```

This way, the outer handler in 'main' can catch it and `continue`.

**Note**: As is, your empty `except:` block in the `for` loop *will catch everything*. Specifying the exception expected (`except ValueError` in this case) is generally considered a good idea.

---

*More simply*, *don't put the body of your validation function `divisible_by_5` in a `try` statement*. Python automatically searches for the nearest except block defined and uses it if the current exception matches the exceptions specified:

```
def raiser():
    if False: 
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError

try:
    raiser()
except ValueError:
    print "caught"
```

This will print `caught`.

Comment: Looked over this.  I see that I didn't add `valueError` to my except line in my main function.  Is that the only difference?

Comment: That and the fact that you don't re-raise the exception; you return `None` in the `except` of `divisible_by_5`. You should specify `except ValueError` in your main and a) either completely remove the `try-except` in the function or b) just replace `return None` with `raise`

Comment: Sorry. just saw your updated answer.  That did the job.  Thank you very much!